# How to make div invisible to still able to click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make div invisible to still able to click?
display hidden or hide() will make it disappear but I want user still able to click it, as i put it on top of another object

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS markup along with whatever javascript you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `<div/>` does not contain any contents, you could:

```
#mydiv {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

See the CSS2.1 property [background-color](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-color)

Answer (score 8):

You could set its `opacity` to `0`. The opacity can be animated using [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('#mydiv').animate({opacity: 0});
```

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks for the heads up, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd like to use `opacity:0;` or `visibility:hidden;`:

```
.element {
  opacity:0;
}
```

or:

```
.element {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Hope it works! Good luck!

Comment: There's no need to post repeated answers (you're basically repeating Asad's). Also, `visiblity` (no double L there) won't work, see my comment on Asad's answer.

Comment: Deleted my comment there as it became outdated. This demonstrates that `visibility: hidden` elements are not clickable:  http://jsfiddle.net/vccym/